# Installing NVIDIA GPU drivers on Azure N-Series VM

Tags: drivers, virtual-machine, azure

I provisioned an NV8as_v4 virtual machine in my Azure subscription. The application I plan on running requires OpenGL 2.0 or greater support so I'm looking at Azure's N-series VMs for their GPU support. However, I'm running into issues getting NVIDIA drivers installed on this machine. Here is what I've tried and the result of each so far:

- Provisioned the VM and attempted to install drivers manually according to instructions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-driver-setup. **Running the executable driver file indicates that no supported video card was found. See Screenshot #1.**
- Provisioned the VM and attempted to install the NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension via the Azure portal (VM > Extensions > Add). **The result of the extension installation was Provisioning Failed and the server ended up in an infinite reboot cycle** (I could log in if I did it quickly enough, but received a warning that a reboot was imminent with a reboot initiated within seconds). I was able to pull up Device Manager before the reboot. **No NVIDIA drivers detected** (see Screenshot #2).
- Deleted the prior VM and provisioned another, this time installing the NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension as part of the VM provisioning (using the Advanced tab on VM setup). **The result of the extension installation was Provisioning Succeeded but I experienced the same reboot behavior as above and Device Manager did not detect the NVIDIA drivers** (See Screenshot #2).

I have to be missing something simple as this seems like basic functionality for an N-Series VM. Any thoughts on how I can get this N-Series VM to install the proper drivers?

**SCREENSHOT #1**

[image: VM can't locate compatible hardware]

**SCREENSHOT #2**

[image: Device manager doesn't show NVIDIA drivers installed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NV8as_v4 virtual machine is using the AMD Radeon Instinct MI25 MxGPU. You can log in (RDP) to your VM, download and install drivers from this link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/9/3893407b-e8aa-4079-8592-735d7dd1c19a/Radeon-Pro-Software-for-Enterprise-GA.exe

You can learn more about the different GPU optimized sizes on this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu

Comment: That was it, thank you! Out of curiosity, where did you find the link to the drivers? I don't see the specific link you provided on that page (or maybe I just missed it). When I follow the links on the page you linked to, I end up here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-amd-driver-setup - this has a different file but the one you provided worked.